# Как сделать сортировку товара и ограничить количество вывода товара на одной странице

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, веб-программирование

Имею страницу с товарами, и нужно сделать ограничение по количеству выводимого товара и сортировку товара по цене и имени. Сортировку пишу(может и не правильно, прошу направить если это так) на php и jquery. Столкнулся с проблемой что не могу добавить две переменные в url, а для сортировки и ограничения скорее всего надо 2е переменные.
имею код jquery, который меняет url, но если я хочу добавить новую переменную, у меня страница зацикливается из-за того что js скрипт перезагружает страницу и добавляет новую переменную, если в url уже есть переменная. Прошу прощение за воду в вопросе, но прошу помочь. **НИЖЕ КОД PHP И JQUERY**

JQUERY

```
function sort()
{
var urlVars = getUrlVars();

if(urlVars.length != 0)
{
    console.log(urlVars[0]);
    window.location.href = window.location.href + "&get=" + 2; // переменная get для того чтобы посмотреть как работает функция( коряво работает(
    console.log(window.location.href + "&get=" + 2);
    
}
}
 sort();
```

getUrlVars function

```
function getUrlVars()
{
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
{
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return vars;
}
```

php

```
                <?
                if($_GET['sortby'] === "name")
                {
                    $query = "SELECT * from products ORDER BY product_name";
                }
                else if($_GET['sortby'] === "price")
                {
                    $query = "SELECT * from products ORDER BY price";
                }
                else
                {
                    $query = "SELECT * from products ORDER BY product_name";
                }


                if($_GET['show'])
                {
                    $query = "SELECT * from products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$_GET['show'];
                }

                $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    echo '<a target="_blank" href="/pages/product-details.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="product-cart">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="product-image"><img src="/images/'.$row['main_image_url'].'" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="product-price-wrap">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="product-name">'.$row['product_name'].'</div>
                                        <div class="product-price">$ '.$row['price'].'</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </a>';
                }
            ?>
```